# How can I simplify the output of `purrr::safely()` and `purrr::map()`?

Tags: r, purrr

I would like to turn the results of `map(.l, safely(f)))` into a data frame.

For example,

```r
# define function
sum_of_dimensions <- function(df){
  stopifnot(nrow(df) < 150)
  result <- nrow(df) + ncol(df)
  return(result)
}

# create list of data frames over which to map
dfs <- list(mtcars = mtcars, iris = iris)

# safely map over dfs
list_safe <- 
  purrr::map(
    dfs,
    purrr::safely(sum_of_dimensions)
  )

# desired results
#>   item   result       error       
#>   <chr>  <named list> <named list>
#> 1 mtcars <int [1]>    <NULL>      
#> 2 iris   <NULL>       <smplErrr>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can create the output you want with

```
  purrr::map(
    dfs,
    purrr::safely(sum_of_dimensions)
  ) %>% tibble::enframe() %>% 
  tidyr::hoist(value, "result","error", .simplify=FALSE)
```

which returns

```
  name   result    error     
  <chr>  <list>    <list>    
1 mtcars <int [1]> <NULL>    
2 iris   <NULL>    <smplErrr>
```

We use `enframe()` to turn the result into a data.frame keeping the list names as a column, then we use `hoist` to extract the nested values. Setting `.simplify=FALSE` keeps everything in list columns.

Comment: Do you know why `unnest_wider(value)` doesn't work here?  When I try that, I get an error that says `x$error` must be a vector, not a <simpleError/error/condition> object.

Comment: The underlying `vctrs` package doesn't know how to combine the error objects into a column. Same thing happens if you use `.simplify=TRUE`. You need to keep those objects as a lift column to put them in a tibble. I don't think `unnest_wider` supports that

Comment: I checked the documentation, and there's a `simplify` argument:  `unnest_wider(value, simplify = FALSE)`.  I wonder why it doesn't work the same way.